# Java with Maven in IntelliJ IDEA: How to properly import a dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I seem unable to import any of my added dependencies. In the following code (pom.xml) we see the JavaFX dependencies which work and the MongoDB dependency which I added myself and don't work.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jonathan.woollettlight</groupId>
    <artifactId>CS-235 A3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.jonathan.woollettlight.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The JavaFX `import` statements which work:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
```

These do not work.

```
import org.mongodb.*;
import org.bson.*;
import com.mongodb.*;
```

With the `import org.bson.*;` giving the error: `Package 'org.bson' is declared in module 'org.mongodb.bson', but module 'com.jonathan.woollettlight' does not read it`. And `import com.mongodb.*;` giving `Package 'com.mongodb' is declared in module 'org.mongodb.driver.sync.client', but module 'com.jonathan.woollettlight' does not read it`

My file structure:

[image]

Expanded external dependencies for MongoDB.

[image]

I tried other dependencies and even followed this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NP6AnvZ0CTA) and that didn't work. I am unable to make any `import` statement on a dependency I've added work.

I should note the project was originally created via the Maven JavaFX archetype.
 To add the archetype use groupId `org.openjfx`, artifactId `javafx-maven-archetypes` and version `0.0.1`.

I am at a loss as to what to do here any help would be greatly appreciated.
Link to project uploaded on google drive if you're that curious/nice (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WKNg1G81dpOhrtO9W3OyRkL-rv10fbvO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What do you mean by  `MongoDB dependency which I added myself and don't work.`? As I can see on your screenshot from IDE the mongodb dependecies are placed properly under `External Libraries`?

Comment: Every `import`statement I try involving the MongoDB dependency doesn't work.

Comment: It would be good to update the description to show which statements are not working, because now we can guess what you mean.

Comment: @PiotrS I added some examples of `import` statements which don't work.

Comment: Could you please expand the maven mongodb dependencies in your external libraries directory ? Java classes seems to be under package com.mongodb.* instead of org.mongodb.*.

Comment: I would make sure you have the latest version of IntelliJ as Java 12 is very new. I would try Java 11 first and try to get that working.

Comment: @Maxime Added a photo of the expanded dependencies and added bit about `import` not working with `com.mongodb.*;`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Tried using JDK11, didn't make any difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded your project and i see the module-info.java contains only javafx.* requires.

```
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
```

Try adding org.mongodb.bson you should be able to import or you can remove the module-info.java file for testing.

I tried both removing the module-info.java for testing and adding the `requires` statements, i was able to add the import statements such as `import org.bson.*;`
I am also using intellij IDE.

**module-info.java**

[image: module-info.java]

**App.java**

[image: App.java]

Answer (score 0):

First of all please make sure that the dependency that you've added indeed accessible by maven, even without IDE:
just run something like: `mvn package` to see that maven downloads the dependency

Now, if the project was imported into idea by opening the pom.xml, intelliJ is supposed to build its internal data based on the information that was found in pom.xml

So the following might help:

**Maven -> "Reimport all maven projects"**  - This will trigger the synchronization process

**Settings -> Build, Execution,Deployment -> Build tools -> Maven**: Maven home directory - intellij might be configured with a different maven than you think you use (has something bundled with ide). Your maven might be pre-configured with some custom properties, proxies, credentials, etc.)

**File -> Close Project** and then open it again, of course open a pom.xml (only if two items above didn't help). This can fix the situation if for some reason intelliJ went into issues of synchronization of its interal data structures with the data from pom.xml, happened a couple of times to me, so I mention this.

Comment: Here's the result of `mvn package` https://hastebin.com/ugagukudoz.cs. None of the other suggested solutions seem to have any affect.

Comment: I also added a link so someone could download the project if they where so curious/nice.